# Android: Start thread, join it and interrupt doesn't work well

Tags: java, android, multithreading, join, interrupt

I have a problem and I can't find the solution on the internet. I saw a lot of examples but no one really answered to my problem.

I have a login page and then, after checked if the both fields (login/pass) are filled, try to connect by another thread.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText login = null;
private EditText password = null;
private RadioButton radioButton = null;
private Button button = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEditText);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.saveRadioButton);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ConnectionButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (login.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                alert(getString(R.string.alertDialoguErrorTitle), getString(R.string.UnfilledFieldLogin));
            } else {
                boolean haveToSave = radioButton.isChecked();

                User user = User.getUser(login.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                try {
                    Intranet.login.start();
                    Intranet.login.join();
                    Intranet.login.interrupt();
                    Intranet.login.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    alert(getString(R.string.alertDialoguErrorTitle), e.toString());
                    login.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                } finally {
                    if (!user._token.equals("")) {
                        if (haveToSave) {
                            // SAVE DATA
                        }
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        login.setText("");
                        password.setText("");
                        alert(getString(R.string.alertDialoguErrorTitle), getString(R.string.badLoginPassword));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void alert(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Close",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // nothing
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

// The class using on the other thread

```
public class Intranet {

public static int responseCode = 0;
public static String responseString = "";

public static Thread login = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private String url = "https://epitech-api.herokuapp.com/login";
    private User user = User.getUser();

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Build the request
            RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("login", user._login)
                    .add("password", user._password)
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();
            Response responses = null;

            // Reset the response code
            responseCode = 0;

            // Make the request
            responses = client.newCall(request).execute();

            if ((responseCode = responses.code()) == 200) {
                // Get response
                String jsonData = responses.body().string();

                // Transform reponse to JSon Object
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                // Use the JSon Object
                user._token = json.getString("token");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        ;
    }
});
}
```

I tried a lot of solutions with join() which wait the end of the thread. But finally, all time at the second time, when I try to connect myself, an exception comes up (The thread is already started). So how can this thread still running if it's  interrupted before continuing?

Comment: Why not just use the Async task ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand very well the difference between async and multi-thread.. 'Cause for me, async is basically based on multi-threading logic, isn't?

Comment: I don't get it. You seem to be wanting to run connecting to the server and validate the login info on a separate thread, and update the UI after that validation completes. Isn't that right ?

Comment: I have a single town class which is about the current user. I use the loginActivity to get the new informations, try to connect with Intranet.login method and then, if everything is ok, I just go back to the MainActivity. The problem is that OkHttp have to be done on different thread...

Comment: Yes. You can accomplish that with an Async task. Please go through some online info or tuts. Basically instead of you starting a thread and waiting for it to join back to the calling thread, you start an async task. What ever task you need to do after your new thread joins is essentially written in the onPostExecute function of the Async task.

Comment: _...an exception comes up (The thread is already started)._  That's right.  A `Thread` instance can only be started one time.  Each time you want to start a new thread, you must create a new `Thread` instance.